# Using AppIdentityCredential with Google Drive API

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I am using Google App Engine Identity to access Google Drive API of a Google Apps user.
I have inserted GAE URL in Manage API client access in Google Apps, with the right scope.

```
AppIdentityCredential credential = new AppIdentityCredential(Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE));
    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
    Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).build();
```

I get this error:

```
com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector handleResponse
WARNING: Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {authsub=WWW-Authenticate: AuthSub realm="https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest" allowed-scopes="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/docs,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly"}
An error occurred: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 OK
{
  "code" : 401,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "Authorization",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "Invalid Credentials",
    "reason" : "authError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid Credentials"
}
```

- Is it necessary to enable GAE application in API Client access in Google Apps? If not, how I authorise GAE app to gain acess to an API Scope?
- Is possible to test GAE Identity in Local / Eclipse?
- Summarizing, what is wrong or lack?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can not debug AppEngine Credentials locally. The only way to debug is to use different credentials (AppEngine for production and Key-based service account locally). It will require to write different code for local and production environment.
2. You need to add your appengine service accounts to Team. If you use custom Google Apps domain for your project than you will need to create email group in your custom domain and add this group. All service accounts should be added to this group.

Comment: Point 1 is incorrect. It is possible to test on a local development appengine. I do it all the time.

Comment: It was not possible a year ago.

Comment: No still not possible. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests ***Note: You can only use AppIdentityCredential credential objects in applications that are running on Google App Engine***

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding the scopes it tries to authenticate against. 
I had the same error in my code and ended up solving in by adding the drive.file scope.

Answer (score 0):

Two important steps

1. Get the Application Default Credentials Service account JSON file.
2. Set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable with the path of the JSON file. Example: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=c:/myFolder/my.jsonfile

FYI:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials